# How to set up port forwarding to access a website hosted on WSL through SSH and intranet penetration

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, wsl-2, ngrok, rstudio-server

**Hi all, here is the premise of my question**:

Our lab just bought a Windows workstation that comes with some softwares for the instruments we also bought. People are coming and going to use these softwares, but I also need to use it for some data analysis using R. Obviously the computer cannot be all mine to use, so I installed WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 on the computer hoping to run rstudio server on it and connect to the R session remotely and write my code.

The R studio server runs fine. I can start the server on WSL, open a localhost:8787 webpage in Windows, and R studio is there.

Then I needed to figure out how to connect WSL to my own laptop. Following [this tutorial](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine), I first SSH to the workstation with Windows SSH and use bash as my default shell. This will automatically launch WSL on the workstation for me to use.

Also, the workstation and my laptop are not in the same network, so I used ngrok to expose the workstation's port 22 for the SSH to go through. I would run
`ngrok tcp 22`
in the workstation's cmd, and this connects port 22 to a public ip such as 0.tcp.ngrok.io:11111. Then from my laptop I run `ssh -p 11111 username@0.tcp.ngrok.io` to access WSL on the workstation.

So far so good. I can connect to the workstation from my laptop and run R on the commandline. The thing is I have no idea how to open the rstudio server webpage on my laptop. I read about port forwarding and tried`ssh -L 8787:localhost:8787 -p 11111 username@0.tcp.ngrok.io` but when I tried to open localhost:8787 on my laptop, it said no data sent from localhost:8787 (or something similar along the line). I searched for solutions and made changes on the WSL side according to [this tutorial](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example#server-side-configuration). After changing, the website is still not working. I also tried setting up a firewall rule on my laptop as `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”Rstudio Server” dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8787` and it does not work neither.

**So my question is**:

How should I set this up properly as there are too many ports going on here: my computer's 8787 port, ngrok's 11111 port, Workstation Windows' 22 port, whatever port that is working with Windows on WSL, and rstudio server's 8787 port.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same struggle with running Anaconda on WSL2 and accessing Jupyter Notebook from outside. What I did is I've installed ZeroTier One on WSL2, it creates virtual network adapter that connects you to a network that you can configure, so if you have ZTO installed on the second computer or phone, it will pretend to be on a local network with all other clients. And then you can connect to your services from any network all around the world. And this ZTO runs serverless, so you actually don't need to host it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question today, hooray! It seems my intuition about too many ports being there isn't entirely wrong. After setting the host name of WSL to another name from localhost following [this tutorial](https://abdus.dev/posts/fixing-wsl2-localhost-access-issue/) and changed nothing else, my laptop knows which website it is supposed to open. So now I can open localhost:8787 on my laptop and use R studio remotely, finally!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm that this procedure also works for remote access to a Jupyter Notebook server running on WSL2.